# Unable to connect to React-Native Voice Call on iPhone se2

Tags: ios, react-native, agora.io

Unable to connect to React-Native Voice Call on iPhone se2

We implemented voice call and video call using Agora SDK for React-native.
However, in iPhone se2, both voice call and video call do not work. All other phones are working fine.
I wonder if agora react-native sdk has restrictions for each device. I can't find any mention of device specific or os specific restrictions on the official site.
If you have that link, please share.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the requirements in the prerequisites [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_react_native?platform=React%20Native#prerequisites).

You need iOS > 8.0, if you're facing issues you can check out the troubleshooting steps [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/react-native-agora#troubleshooting).